# Javascript Form Validate

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to validate input on an HTML form. I am trying to use one script to validate various forms that have several similar elements. All in all there are about 15 different fields but I am only putting 3. Below works on the form that has all of the elements but fails on any form that does not have a specific field.

```
if (form.name.value == ""){ // Check if blank
    alert( "\nEnter a name." );
    form.name.focus();
    return false; // Stop the form processing.
    } 

else if ( !/^\w{10}$/.test( form.phone.value )) { // Check for phone
    form.name.style.border=""
    alert( "\nEnter a valid phone number!" );
    form.phone.focus();
    return false; // Stop the form processing.
    } 

else{
 return true; // Submit!
```

Since this only works if all are present what i want to do is validate only if it exists. I have tried nesting the validation under a statement that should check for the element before trying to validate it and if the element doesn't exist it should move on to the next.

```
if (document.forms[0].name){ //does field exist?
    if (form.name.value === ""){
        alert( "\nEnter a name." );
        form.name.focus();
        return false; // Stop the form processing.
        }
    else{
        return true; //field ok move on.
        }
    }

else if (document.forms[0].phone){
    if ( !/^\w{10}$/.test( form.phone.value )) {  user
        form.name.style.border=""
        alert( "\nEnter a valid phone number!" );
        form.phone.focus();
        return false; // Stop the form processing.
        } 
    else{
        return true; //field ok move on.
        }
    }
else{
       return true; // Submit!
}
```

Any help help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your "phone" regex does not seem very useful...

Comment: I have a seperate function that strips spaces and non numerics onblur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present you are checking that (document.forms[0].name) is available and then if this is dead it check if (document.forms[0].phone) is true and then...... and then if none are true it resorts to the 'else' and returns are true. The use of `if else` means that you only bother with anything after if this part has failed.

You could try.

```
if (document.forms[0].name) {
    if ( !/^\w{10}$/.test( form.phone.value )) {  user
        form.name.style.border=""
        alert( "\nEnter a valid phone number!" );
        form.phone.focus();
        return false; // Stop the form processing.
    } 
}
if (document.forms[0].blah) {
    do stuff...
    if fail
        return false;
}
return true;
```

As the function is going to return as true anyway, you don't need to state return true anywhere else (also this will stop the process as it has `returned` and stopped). The only reason to stop the process if things have gone wrong.. hence `return false;`

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to validate a form, you don't need to write javascript nowadays. You can use [html5 forms](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/). Even if you have to support browser without this feature, you can put the [webshims lib](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/webforms.html) at your page to enable it.